# HTA, VBScript and powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, hta

I've got a problem with HTA page with powershell scripts. This page show the end-user, when script receive correct version then close hta page, when was incorrect, the show page and wait to accept user to install.

When I run powershell script from cli, i received correct information

file ver.ps1

```
$FSecure_Current = "9.52.239"
$Currentversion = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion |where {$_.DisplayName -match "F-Secure Client Security - Ochrona przed wirusami i szpiegami"}
    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion |where {$_.DisplayName -match "F-Secure Client Security - Virus & Spy Protection"}
    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion |where {$_.DisplayName -match "F-Secure Client Security - Ochrona przed wirusami i szpiegami"}
    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion |where {$_.DisplayName -match "F-Secure Client Security - Virus & Spy Protection"}
} |
 Select-Object DisplayVersion
# Check if F-Secure is installed:
if(("$Currentversion" -match "$FSecure_Current" ))
{
$FSecure_Current
$FSecure_akt = 'correct_version'
Write-host $FSecure_akt
$FSecure_akt | clip
}
else {
$FSecure_Current
$FSecure_nakt = 'incorrect_version'
Write-host $FSecure_nakt
$FSecure_nakt | clip
}
```

When i run this script from hta file, I always get incorrect version
MOT.hta

```
<html>
    <head>
    <HTA:APPLICATION
        APPLICATIONNAME="Message"
        SCROLL="no"
        SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
        WINDOWSTATE="Normal"
        CAPTION="yes"
        MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
        MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
        BORDER="thin"
        BORDERSTYLE="Normal"
        CONTEXTMENU="no"
        SELECTION="no"
        SYSMENU="yes"
</head>

<title>Message</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<SCRIPT language="VBScript">
    Dim pbTimerID
    Dim pbHTML 
    Dim pbWaitTime
    Dim pbHeight
    Dim pbWidth
    Dim pbBorder
    Dim pbUnloadedColor
    Dim pbLoadedColor
    Dim pbStartTime

    Dim oShell, scriptPath, appCmd, retVal, retData
    Set oShell  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'   scriptPath  = oShell.CurrentDirectory & "\ver.ps1"
    appCmd      = "powershell -noexit -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted .\ver.ps1"
    retVal      = oShell.Run(appCmd)
    retData     = window.clipboarddata.getdata("Text")
    If(retData = "correct_version") Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Self.Close
    Else

    End If

Sub RunScript_Paste
    DataArea.InnerHTML = document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("text")
End Sub

    Sub Window_OnLoad
        window.resizeTo 1024,950
        ' Progress Bar Settings
        pbWaitTime = 900        ' How many seconds the progress bar lasts
        pbHeight = 10       ' Progress bar height
        pbWidth= 380        ' Progress bar width
        pbUnloadedColor="white"     ' Color of unloaded area
        pbLoadedColor="black"       ' Color of loaded area
        pbBorder="grey"     ' Color of Progress bar border

        ' Don't edit these things
        pbStartTime = Now
        rProgressbar
        pbTimerID = window.setInterval("rProgressbar", 200)

    End Sub

    Sub rProgressbar
        pbHTML = ""
        pbSecsPassed = DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now)
        pbMinsToGo =  Int((pbWaitTime - pbSecsPassed) / 60)
        pbSecsToGo = Int((pbWaitTime - pbSecsPassed) - (pbMinsToGo * 60))
        if pbSecsToGo < 10 then
            pbSecsToGo = "0" & pbSecsToGo 
        end if
        pbLoadedWidth = (pbSecsPassed / pbWaittime) * pbWidth
        pbUnloadedWidth = pbWidth - pbLoadedWidth
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<table border=1 bordercolor=" & pbBorder & " cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=" & pbWidth & "><tr>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<th width=" & pbLoadedWidth & " height=" & pbHeight & "align=left bgcolor="  & pbLoadedColor & "></th>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<th width=" & pbUnloadedWidth & " height=" & pbHeight & "align=left bgcolor="  & pbUnLoadedColor & "></th>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "</tr></table><br>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=" & pbWidth & "><tr>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbMinsToGo & ":" & pbSecsToGo & "</td>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "</tr></table>"
        progressbar.InnerHTML = pbHTML
        if DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now) >= pbWaitTime then
            StopTimer
            DoAction
        end if
    End Sub

    Sub StopTimer
        window.clearInterval(PBTimerID)
    End Sub

    Sub DoAction
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        appCmd1      = "powershell -noexit -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted .\reinstall.ps1"
        retVal      = oShell.Run(appCmd1)
        Self.close
    End Sub

    Sub Action
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        appCmd1      = "powershell -noexit -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted .\reinstall.ps1"
        retVal      = oShell.Run(appCmd1)
    End Sub

</SCRIPT>

<body>
<p> </p>
<p><font size="8"><b>Blah Blah Blah</font></b></p>

<p><font size="6"><i>Blah Blah Blah</font></b>
</p>
<p>
<b>Blah Blah Blah
</b>
</i></p>
<p><i><font color="red">
Blah Blah Blah
</font></i></p>
<p><font size="8" color="red"><b>Blah Blah Blah</b></font></p><br>
<br>Blah Blah Blah
</p>
<br>
<div align="center">
<font size="4" color="red"><b>Auto install process:</b></font><br>
<span id = "progressbar"></span>
    <input type="Button" value="Write documents and close application to process install" name="button1" onClick="Action" class="button">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `powershell .\script.ps1` -> `powershell -File .\script.ps1`?

Comment: What do you mean "I always get incorrect version". Is it looking for the version in the registry? Where does it get this version? I note you have `On Error Resume Next` You should start by removing this and doing some basic debugging. Is the version meant to be returned in retVal in the hta? Is it blank or just the wrong number? Has this HTA ever worked?

Comment: In register i've got a value 9.52.239. When I run powershell script from cli i receive correct_version. But when i run HTA, i receive incorrect_version

Comment: This is simple a matter of troubleshooting. Try to pinpoint the issue by revealing information like: `write-host $Currentversion` or: what happens if you replace `if(("$Currentversion" -match "$FSecure_Current" ))` with `If ($True) {...`

Comment: Thx iRon. I change powershell script as your suggest and it work.